# Dump file analysis of Java process?

Tags: java, debugging, windbg

If I take dump, using Windbg, of Java process running on Windows

Can I analyze (easly?) the Java heap, objects, and threads?

Just like I could do with SOS for .Net process?

Otherwise - how can I offline debug a problem happening on production systems?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

Windows minidumps (.dmp) can be used with these utilities:

1. `jvisualvm` utility from JDK can get you both thread dump and heap dump

   - Open `jvisualvm`
   - In the `Applications` pane, find `VM Coredumps`
   - Right-click it
   - Select `Add VM Coredump...`
   - Browse to your `.dmp` minidump file
   - Press `OK`
   - Right-click the new item under `VM Coredumps`
   - Select `Thread Dump`
   - Repeat for `Heap Dump`
2. `jstack` utility from JDK can show Java stack from Windows minidumps (.dmp)

   Here's a batch script for that:

   ```
   :: Shows java stack from Windows minidumps
   :: Argument %1: Path to minidump
   @ECHO OFF

   SET JDK_PATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin

   "%JDK_PATH%\jstack.exe" "%JDK_PATH%\java" "%~1"
   PAUSE
   ```
3. `jmap` utility from JDK can convert Windows minidump (.dmp) to java heap dump (.hprof)

   Here's a batch script for that:

   ```
   :: Converts Windows minidump to Java heap dump (.hprof)
   :: Argument %1: Path to minidump
   @ECHO OFF

   SET JDK_PATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin

   "%JDK_PATH%\jmap.exe" -F -dump:format=b,file="%~dpn1.hprof" "%JDK_PATH%\java" "%~1"
   PAUSE
   ```

Comment: I understand this is an old thread but - When I try to open a DMP file created through Task Manager (64-bit java process/application) I get the following error:

"c:\Temp\ApplicationName.DMP is not a valid core dump!"

I have tried the visualvm instead of jvisualbv, but it doesn't have a "VM Coredumps" option showing.

Comment: Hi @BrianBooth, i generated my `.dmp` file from the Task Manager, by right-clicking on `java.exe`, then `Create dump file`. Then, i followed the Steps described by Codeguard for `jvisualvm`, and it works perfectly. Did you create a dumpfile from a `java` process? I reproduce your error, by creating a dump file for a `Chrome` process, and when i try to add the item under `jvisualvm - VM Coredumps`, it tells me `chrome.DMP is not a valid core dump!`

Comment: I have the same issue as Brian with visualvm 2.1.6

Comment: Is the JDK you're using the same as JDK used by target program?

Answer (score 7):

[jvisualvm](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html) can be used to load a dump and then analyze it

**EDIT:**

This comes in the JDK redist...

Comment: That tool can be used to view a Windows Crash Dump file (.dmp)? I don't see a way to do this.

Comment: @Bryan Java heap dump; you can dump within the tool; providing a point in time of the state of the JVM you were monitoring.

Answer (score 5):

There's a [Java Heap Analysis Tool](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jhat.html)

Comment: s far as I understand, it can't open windows minidumps (.dmp) described in question

Answer (score 0):

NetBeans 6.9.1 can load .hprof file (Profile -> Load Heap Dump). Then, for example, you can search for the biggest object and see it's internals.