# Create a java heap dump from a windows memory dump

Tags: java, debugging, heap-memory

I have a windows memory dump (DMP) file of a JVM process.

> Is there any way I can use Java tooling to do a heap analysis of this? The SDK tools (jhat etc.) don't seem to help - they all seem to expect a Java heap dump.

(I've plenty of **Windbg** experience, but I am a complete ignoramus when it comes to Java debugging)

This similar question: [Dump file analysis of Java process?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3883029/87427) has no answer on this point.

Comment: Why don't you just do a heap dump with [`jmap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jmap.html), and then analyze it in [`Eclipse MAT`](http://www.eclipse.org/mat), for example?

Comment: Because all I have been given is a DMP file... the process is long gone. This is post-mortem analysis.

Comment: I don't believe there is a way to convert a core dump into a heap dump. All the Java tools are designed to use heap dumps.

Comment: jmap support extracting stuff from unix core file.. see if this work for windows as well. (this is new in jdk 7)

Comment: Which JDK you are using Oracle/IBM ?

Comment: I've just got the standard Oracle download right now. Some searching on the net showed up an IBM tool called "jextract" which may (?) do a conversion to a format jmap can read - but I can't figure out if/how I can download it for free. It doesn't seem like jmap can handle windows DMP files natively.

Comment: @JamesWorld Are you analyzing a JVM crash?

Comment: @JamesWorld did you ever solve this? I too have been given a (DMP) file. 13G of a wildfly server that was having issues. If I can solve this without trying to recreate the issue... In this case the server didn't crash but was very close to doing so.

Comment: Figured it out. Use this: jmap -F -dump:format=b,file=jvm.hprof "C:\Development\Tools\jdk1.8.0_171\bin\ava.exe" java.DMP  just in case someone else comes down this road.

Answer (score 1):

See [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883029/dump-file-analysis-of-java-process/52523489#52523489) covering exactly that, how to get Java information from Windows minidump

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question properly then i would suggest you to use jconsole you can find under jdk.

You can find API here

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jconsole.html